# Error in dimnames(slot(x, "coords") when running align_move in move package

Tags: r, move

I am trying to run an animation in *Move* and *MoveVis 0.10.1* package and I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in dimnames(slot(x, "coords")) <-`*vtmp*` : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

, which I am not sure what it means. My data structure is set up similar to the example data set so I am not sure where I am going wrong.

The columns are set to:

```
`str(pdfhrecenttracks2)
'data.frame':   10312 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ location.long: num  -90.6 -90.6 -90.6 -91 -91 ...
 $ location.lat : num  41.5 41.5 41.5 41.4 41.4 ...
 $ time         : POSIXct, format: "2018-06-05 00:05:18" ...
 $ coords.x1    : num  -90.6 -90.6 -90.6 -91 -91 ...
 $ coords.x2    : num  41.5 41.5 41.5 41.4 41.4 ...
 $ optional     : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ sensor       : Factor w/ 1 level "unknown": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ timestamps   : POSIXct, format: "2018-06-05 00:05:18" ...
 $ trackId      : Factor w/ 121 levels "T12414","T12415",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

`pdfh <- move(x=pdfhrecenttracks2$location.long, y=pdfhrecenttracks2$location.lat,time=as.POSIXct(pdfhrecenttracks2$timestamps, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC"), data=pdfhrecenttracks2, proj=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 + towgs84=0,0,0"), animal=pdfhrecenttracks2$trackId, sensor= pdfhrecenttracks2$sensor)
`m <- align_move(pdfh, res = 240, unit = "secs")

`n <- 121
`color = grDevices::colors()[grep('gr(a|e)y', > grDevices::colors(), invert = T)]
`unique.colors <- sample(color, n)
`pie(rep(1,n), col=unique.colors)

`frames <- frames_spatial(m, path_colours = unique.colors, map_service = "osm", map_type = "watercolor", alpha = 0.5) %>% add_labels(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude") %>% # add some customizations, such as axis labels
  add_northarrow() %>% 
  add_scalebar() %>% 
  add_timestamps(m, type = "label") %>% 
  add_progress()

`m <- align_move(pdfh, res = 240, unit = "secs")

Error in dimnames(slot(x, "coords")) <- `*vtmp*` : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
4: In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
5: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
6: In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
7: In max.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
8: In min.default(numeric(0), na.rm = FALSE) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

Comment: Hello, was this solved? I just had the same problem. Maybe it is a good idea to write to the owners of the package. I had this problem specifically with the functions `align_move`

Comment: Sorry this was awhile ago, but I believe the error was attributed to certain individuals only having one sampling location. For align_move, a minimum of two locations is required per tagged individual.

Comment: Hi! Indeed, this was the problem here. When I eliminated the individuals with less than 10 locations (they had 8 and 9 locations each, respectively), the code worked fine. Anyway, it would be nice to know the minimum amount of many data points are necessary for running the animations...
Thanks for the hint!